# What's the right way to update an array of nested C structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I'm having trouble finding the right way to mutate members of an array of nested structs in C99 (after passing the array to another function). The array is declared within main() - so it's on the stack, I presume? - and, I may as well just show the relevant parts of the code.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t x, y;
} point;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t r, g, b, a;
} rgba;

typedef struct
{
    point a, b, c;
    rgba p;
} tri;
```

Those are the structs; here's how I create a random triangle (an ability I need in other parts of the program):

```
tri triangle()
{
    tri t;

    t.a.x = rand() % xres;
    t.a.y = rand() % yres;
    t.b.x = rand() % xres;
    t.b.y = rand() % yres;
    t.c.x = rand() % xres;
    t.c.y = rand() % yres;
    t.p.r = rand() % 256;
    t.p.g = rand() % 256;
    t.p.b = rand() % 256;
    t.p.a = rand() % 256;

    return t;
}
```

And here's the part (some lines you can ignore) where I declare and populate the array:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    init(argc, argv[1]);

    uint32_t img[xres][yres];

    copyInputImage(img);

    srand(time(NULL));

    tri trigons[NUM_TRIGONS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIGONS; i++)
    {
        trigons[i] = triangle();
    }
```

All that successfully gets me an array of random triangles.

Now here's my problem: depending on the program parameters, sometimes I want to immediately re-populate the array with data from a text file. The text format is simple: one unsigned char on every line. Here's an example of what the data for a single pixel looks like in that file:

```
0
40
0
5
37
31
134
64
167
100
```

That's an example of the 10 primitives a triangle struct ultimately needs. All number strings are 3 digits or less, but my loop with *fgets()* involves a 5-char buffer to allow for the line terminator and the null terminator.

The function that does that looks like this:

```
void read_SVG(char* filename, tri* ts)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    char str[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIGONS; i++)
    {
        tri *t   = &(ts[i]);
        point *a = &(ts[i]).a;
        point *b = &(ts[i]).b;
        point *c = &(ts[i]).c;
        rgba  *p = &(ts[i]).p;

        while (fgets(str, 5, fp) != NULL)
        {
            a->x = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            a->y = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            b->x = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            b->y = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            c->x = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            c->y = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            p->r = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            p->g = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            p->b = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
            p->a = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
        }
        t->a = *a;
        t->b = *b;
        t->c = *c;
        t->p = *p;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

And finally, this is how I invoke *read_SVG()*, shown within its context in *main()*.

```
if (argc > 2)
{
    read_SVG(argv[2], trigons);

    draw(screen, trigons);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    SDL_SaveBMP(screen, "wtf.bmp");
    exit(0);
}
```

When I output the array from within this *read_SVG()*, it looks like the data I expected. But when I examine it back in *main()*, it looks like the random values that I'd initially populated.

So it seems the initial array was never updated at all. What have I done wrong, and can anyone suggest an overall better way of handling this type of nested struct pass and update problem?

I'm sure many questions about this have been asked; I can only hope mine will be comprehensive enough to help out some other C newbies. I tried a wide variety of approaches before coming here for help...

Comment: One of the wrong things in this code is returning a local structure from `triangle()`. Local vars are created on stack, and upon returning from the function its stack frame is discarded. It\`s better to pass a pointer to the structure as a parameter.

Comment: He's returning a structure, which will be done via a copy in the calling code. it's innefficient, but effectively no different than returning a local int.

Comment: Right; I have -Wall on and I do normally get the error when I'm returning something that will be lost after the stack frame is discarded. The code I've posted in this question throws no warnings even with -Wextra.

Comment: @kdopen: Damn. Mea culpa. Sorry for misinformation.

Comment: I think we need to see the lines from ma∈ma∈main around the call to readSVGreadSVGread_SVG - including the `printf` calls.

Comment: I just added the area in `main()` where I invoke the SVG read function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is redundant, since a,b,c, and p already points to the same memory that t points to:

```
    t->a = *a;
    t->b = *b;
    t->c = *c;
    t->p = *p;
```

But that's just a nitpick. ;) The *important* comment is probably that fgets() will read all file contents for the first item, and read nothing for the rest of the items. Maybe s/while/if/?

Edit to clarify: Here's an alternative version of the read_SVG() function:

```
void read_SVG(char* filename, tri* ts)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    char str[5];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < NUM_TRIGONS && fgets(str, 5, fp) != NULL) {
        uint32_t val = (uint32_t) strtol(str, NULL, 10);
        ts[i].a.x = ts[i].a.y = 
        ts[i].b.x = ts[i].b.y = 
        ts[i].c.x = ts[i].c.y = 
        ts[i].p.r = ts[i].p.g = ts[i].p.b = ts[i].p.a = val;

        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that `fgets` returns a single line, and automatically iterates to the next line on its next call? So I just loop until it returns NULL, signifying the end of the file.

If what you are saying is true, why is it I can modify the function to populate its own array, which when printed out will show exactly what I want: one number per line, perfectly matching the text input I gave it.

Comment: Your understanding of fgets() is correct. The problem is that the index into the tri-array is incremented outside the while-loop. Since the while-loop reads all data from the file for item #1 (i == 0), the fgets() function will return NULL for all other values of i.

Comment: I am seeing your point, and I like your idea. But I tried pasting in your version; I also tried adding `rewind(fp)` to mine, and in both cases I ended up with a totally black output image, rather than the one the text file should have produced..

Comment: Post some sample lines from the input file, maybe someone can help you figuring out what else is wrong. (Maybe there's a bug in the draw() function?)

Comment: "Here's an example of what the data for a single pixel looks like in that file:" There's your problem right there. The code reads one line from the file and use it for all members.  All coordinates will have the same values, leading to very small triangles...

Can you change the file format? If so, go for one line per Triangle. If not, read one line for each struct member.

Comment: OH MY GOD of course, you were right. I write all that code, revise it repeatedly, describe it in detail here... and what a silly problem in the end.

Please tell me I'm not the only person who makes such mistakes in C!